# rotating player in minimap

Tags: c#, system.drawing

Im trying to rotate player icon according to players facing.

```
                Image pImage = Image.FromFile("player.png");
                Bitmap pBitmap = new Bitmap(pImage.Width, pImage.Height);
                Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pBitmap);
                gfx.RotateTransform(10);
                gfx.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gfx.DrawImage(pImage, new Point(0, 0));
                gfx.Dispose();

                g.DrawImage(pImage, 150 - RADAR_ICON_WIDTH / 2, 150 - RADAR_ICON_HEIGHT / 2, RADAR_ICON_WIDTH, RADAR_ICON_HEIGHT);
```

the following code does not rotate at all :( the player.png (a arrowicon) is only pointing upwards (default position) at all times :(

Comment: i've edited the code... please take another look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little searching the web i found these two sites:

- [Image rotation by angle](http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/image-rotation-by-angle-SID600.aspx)
- [How to Rotate Image in Picture Box Using C#](http://r4r.co.in/c1/01/tutorial/csharp/How%20to%20Rotate%20Image%20using%20c-sharp.shtml)

If i take a look into these codes it seems that you are missing a call to [`TranslateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4.aspx) before and after calling [`RotateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662.aspx).